# How can I review some release notes?

Tags: debian, apt, documentation, deb

Two days ago I upgraded several packages. I remember reading something important after the packages were downloaded and before they were installed, but only now I think any action is necessary. However, I  can't remember the exact instructions I was given and am looking for the release notes to refresh my memory.

How can I find the release notes of the last packages I upgrade?

I have searched in these locations:

- /var/log/dpkg.log
- /var/log/apt/history.log
- /var/log/apt/term.log

But these files don't seem to contain what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The log files you list will give you the names of the packages you upgraded. To find the changelogs, look at

```
/usr/share/doc/${package}/changelog.Debian.gz
```

and possibly

```
/usr/share/doc/${package}/NEWS.Debian.gz
```

for each upgraded package `${package}`. The latter is what would be shown by default during upgrades.

You'll also find “upstream” changelogs and release notes, if any, in `/usr/share/doc/${package}/changelog.gz` and `/usr/share/doc/${package}/NEWS.gz`.