# How can I (re)show post-installation notes?

Tags: debian, debian-installer

Occasionally, a package shows a post-install message. How can I replay this message for a given package on a Debian system?

Compare to FreeBSD: `pkg info -D PACKAGE`
Compare to MacPorts: `port notes PACKAGE`

What's the Debian equivalent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the message is also included in the package’s changelog or news, you can consult those to see it again; see [How can I review some release notes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/333304/86440) for details.

If the message was displayed by the package itself as part of its installation, there’s no general rule. You can try

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow PACKAGE
```

to re-run the package configuration, which might show the message again; but some packages remember what they’ve shown, to avoid showing it twice... In such cases you could look at the package ”templates” in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/PACKAGE.templates`, or examine its post-installation script in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/PACKAGE.postinst` to figure out what it does, but that’s hardly a generalisable approach. For example, `debian-security-support` can be reset by deleting `/var/lib/debian-security-support/security-support.semaphore`; `sudo dpkg-reconfigure debian-security-support` will then show its information again.